# JS event independent of finger pressure

Tags: javascript, android, ios, events, scroll

So, basically, I have a JS event which is activated when you arrive at a certain scroll position.

It works well on desktop browser, but not on mobile browser. You have to wait for the finger leaving the screen.

Would it be possible to activate the event even if the finger is still scrolling the page ?

Comment: What event are you using?  I'd imagine you'd need to use the `onMouseDown` handler, not the `onClick` or `onMouseUp` handlers.

Comment: I'm using `$(document).bind('touchmove', function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that mobile browsers freeze all DOM manipulation and javascript during scrolls.  So I'm not sure what you are trying to do is possible.