# Native scroll event and JS execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, mobile

Ok for starters I know this is somewhat of a repeat to this ([JS event independent of finger pressure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416668/js-event-independent-of-finger-pressure)).

I am interested in a slightly more in-depth answer.

I understand that native scroll on most if not all devices pause the execution of JS and DOM manipulation. But I'd like to understand if possible why this happens, and maybe grab some suggestions on how to maybe side-step the issue.

I've got the following:

```
DataBar.prototype = {
    init: function(){
        this.percentage = this.getPercentage(this.used);
    },
    getPercentage: function(used){
        return (this.total.match(/unlimited/i)) ? 100 : 100 - ( (100 / parseInt(this.total)) * parseInt(used) );
    },
    setUsage: function(used){
        var t = this;
        if( used || used === 0){
            this.percentage = this.getPercentage( used );
        }

        //*******ANIMATION BLOCK*********//
        if(this.CSStransition){
            this.bar[0].style.width = this.percentage+'%';
            this.bar.one('transitionend',transitionEnd);
        } else {
            this.bar.animate({
                width: t.percentage+'%'
            }, t.opts.speed, transitionEnd);
        }
        //*******ANIMATION BLOCK*********//

        function transitionEnd(){
            t.ele[ t.percentage > 20 ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('warn');
        }
        this.remaining.text(this.getRemaining());
    },
    getRemaining: function(){
        if( this.total.match(/unlimited/i) ){
            return 'unlimited';
        }
        return (~~this.total - ~~this.used) + (this.name === 'data' ? 'Mb' : '') + ' left';
    }
};
```

With focus on the animation block, any suggestions?

I need to somehow force the animation to continue, this as I understand it is not possible. But due to the nature of the display, I cannot afford for the animation to pause while scrolling.

Shooting for the impossible here, but is there any way to continue the animation on touch & drag?

Comment: You probably could do this by completely taking control of the touch events. If you just run a function `ontouchmove`, then it should work. What I mean by this is to `preventDefault`, and then making the page scroll via your own script, so that the normal DOM events won't be cancelled. I'm not suggesting to manually take over the JS animation when you're scrolling via touchmove events.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try tonight and see what I can concoct